# SQL "like" statement: 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff' = false?

Tags: sql

**EDIT: Problem solved. It was my reading that was incorrect, not the SQL :p**

Hi!

I was just reading in my database book about the LIKE SQL statement. It said this:

```
SELECT whatever FROM whereever WHERE 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff';
```

It continued to say that the statement 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff' would always return false. The book did not tell me why, nor can I find this anywhere else. Does this then mean that the following SQL also would return null?

```
SELECT W.name FROM whereever W WHERE w.name LIKE 'Jeff';
```

For reference, the book is: 
*Database Management Systems: Ramakrishnan - Gehrke* From McGRAW - Hill. International edition. ISBN 0-07-123151-X PAGE 140.

Comment: That is incorrect, at least for SQL Server. `select 1 WHERE 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff'` returns `1`.

Comment: That does not seem right at all... in fact, I just tested it with SQL Server and that is not true.  Is there perhaps some context missing to this quote?

Comment: See my answer: the poster has copied incorrectly from the book, which has a space in one of the strings and is making a point about how LIKE handles blanks.

Comment: Can you provide the exact quote and text please? Perhaps there is something else. x like x is perfectly and reasonably correct in all mainstream systems.

Comment: Just for fun i will quote the book:

"Note that unlike the other comparison opeartors, blanks can be significant for the LIKE opeartor(depending on the collation for the underlying character set). Thus, 'Jeff' = 'Jeff' is true while 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff' is false."

Comment: Again, you're misreading the book.  There's a space after Jeff in the second item in each example.  It's `Thus, 'Jeff'='Jeff ' is true while 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff ' is false`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took a look at that page (Amazon "search inside [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072465638)") and the key thing that you're missing is that the author is making a point there about whitespace.  The book actually says

```
Thus, 'Jeff'='Jeff ' is true, while 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff ' is false.
```

Note the spaces!

Just to make it clear why the mistake occurred, here's the text:

[image]

Since the space is at the end of the line, it's hard to see.  But as I say below, the quote mark wouldn't wrap to the next line if there were no space there.

Comment: +1 Brilliant! I was trying to figure out how to find the source, didn't think of Amazon search inside :)

Comment: Omg... so there is supposed to be a space. :(

the space is at the end of a line, so it seems as though there is no space. It really is no space there. it says " 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff" new line "'".

Comment: Yeah, it's at the end of a line, making it hard to see it.  One point is that if there weren't a space there, convention is that the quote mark wouldn't wrap to the next line.  (But also, when I did an Amazon "search within the book", the search results repeated the text and I could see the spaces clearly.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL would disagree with your book (not sure about other DBMSes):

```
mysql> SELECT 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff';
+--------------------+
| 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff' |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It states that the book uses SQL:1999, maybe that was the standard back then :p

Thanks :)

Comment: MSSQL disagrees with the book, as well. I'm suspecting the book was misinterpreted.

Comment: Can't accept answer for another 6 min:p

Love stackoverflow <3

Comment: Yes -- in the book the example has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would say that - 'Jeff' like 'Jeff' is exactly true. In which case, it will return ALL the rows from 'whereever'

In your second statement, it will only return rows where the the 'name' column is exactly 'Jeff'. If it is 'Jeff something', it won't return. If you want to return something like that, then you have to do something like 'w.name like 'Jeff%'. There are many more variations of this, which I'm sure you'll discover as you read on more...

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the DBMS implementation, but if you run "select 'jeff' like 'jeff';" from MySQL it return "1" (aka true).

Answer (score 0):

Totally false. The following statement returns 'Y' (because the condition evaluates to true:

```
select 'Y' where 'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff'
```

... while this statement returns no rows (because it evaluates to false):

```
select 'Y' where 'Jeff' LIKE 'John'
```

I don't know what these authors were thinking, but LIKE comparisons without any wildcards are perfectly acceptable; the left and right sides are compared semantically for exact equality.

Answer (score 0):

That section of the book deals with blanks.  They are saying that, in sql,

'Jeff' = 'Jeff ' (note the extra space) results in TRUE but

'Jeff' LIKE 'Jeff ' (again, with the extra space) results in FALSE

Hope that clears things up.